# Is the [completeness] tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, blacklisted-tags

I have noticed today that we have a [completeness](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/completeness) tag. It currently houses seven different questions on widely different notions of completeness.

Since there are widely different notions of completeness in mathematics, there is a lot of room for misuse with this tag.

I therefore suggest that we follow the footsteps of Math.SE and blacklist this tag altogether.

Comment: You might have already noticed comments under Todd Trimble's answer, but just to make sure - is this proposal about ([tag:completion]) tag, too?

Comment: I saw. I did mean the completeness tag, though. It was a huge mess.

Comment: It's not necessary, it only exists for completeness... Sorry, please publicly flog me; I definitely deserve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable thing to do. If there are no objections, then I'll set the wheels in motion.

Update: After removing completeness tags by hand (from the 7 posts that used it), I had put in a request to SE Community Management to blacklist that tag. I've not heard back from them though.

Second update: As per Shog9's comment, the completeness tag has been blacklisted.

Comment: Is ([tag:completion]) being removed too - https://mathoverflow.net/posts/268770/revisions and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268770/doesnt-completion-of-a-representation-ring-preserve-its-indecomposables#comment664675_268770? (I see that completeness has already been manually removed from all questions.)

Comment: Oh, good point. There are 24 questions currently with the 'completion' tag. It has no usage guideline. We should discuss.

Comment: Regarding that (one) instance of the completion tag that was removed: it's been restored, as no one has expressed feelings that the tag is generally problematic at the moment. (Might be nice to have a usage guideline at some point though.)

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Comment: Tag is now blacklisted; it can no longer be used.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the update!